# Two variables getting 404 for CSS and Image urls

Tags: php, html, css, apache, .htaccess

I am working on simple database project on my server. Need to update my database or not by passing parameter on URL.

For example:

```
http://example.com/3000
```

No need to update the db and display value 3000

If i use

```
http://example.com/3000/update
```

than need to update my db...

However my .htaccess and php script working fine... But my CSS and images file not working while update URL and i got 404 error on CSS/JS files.

I checked the URL for css, it can be rewrite like this

```
http://example.com/3000/theme.css
```

Actual URL is

```
http://example.com/theme.css
```

**My .HTACCESS file**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/update$ index.php?result=$1&update=true [L] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$  db.php?result=$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

How to fix this problem.. What mistake done on htaccess file..

Comment: FYI: Client side files cannot be rewrite or map in htaccess. If you need to update your urls to `/3000/theme.css` why don't you update their urls in your template file.

Comment: lol..i know the problem at server side at htaccess. By the way 3000 is a value not a directory to update.  if i process any value http://example.com/200/update  than css url go like this http://example.com/200/theme.css